# How can I have a jQuery onclick function return the element instead of the event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function called deleteTask which currently just does `console.log(this)`

`<input type="button" value="Delete Task" onclick="deleteTask()"/>` (note that this in a jQuery function, not in a HTML file) returns `[object Window]`

while `del.onclick = deleteTask;` (where del is the input button) returns the object that was clicked, in this case, `<input>`

How can I have the jQuery version output similarly to the pure JS one?

Comment: What does that have to do with jQuery?

Comment: I may have been wrong to flag this as jQuery, but the`<input type="button" value="Delete Task" onclick="deleteTask()"/>`  code snippet is in a jQuery function

aka something like

`<$('#createTask').on('click', () => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but it is generally better to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
function deleteTask() {
  console.log(this)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Delete Task" onclick="deleteTask.call(this)" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!

If I may ask, what makes using addEventListener better?

Comment: @asko1 Happy to help. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/9513184

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you'd set it up like this:

html:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Task" data-role='delete' />
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('[data-role=delete]').click( deleteTask )
})

function deleteTask() {
  // element clicked is this -- or if you want it ready for JQ: $(this)
}
```

Comment: The actual element is `this`. `$(this)` wraps it in a jQuery object.